# Работа с проксями в C при помощи сокетов линукса

Tags: linux, c, proxy, unix-socket

Как установить соединение с сервером через прокси, используя сокеты линукса на языке C?
Хотелось бы увидеть примеры подключения к http прокси и отправки через нее запроса на сервер.

Comment: А видов проксей много. Вам какую? Но обычно все сводиться к тому, что нужно подключиться к проксе (хост-порт известен) и послать ей запрос, уточнив, кому переслать его.

Comment: Мне нужно понять,как ей отправить этот запрос.Как он должен выглядить,какие заголовки и тд.

Comment: Вам какую проксю? есть http, socks4/sock5, ssl прокси

Comment: http и socks4/5.

Comment: Линкуйтесь с `libproxy` — делов-то! https://libproxy.github.io/libproxy/

Comment: А без нее? Используя только стандартные линукс библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

- socks4 - [описание](https://github.com/h12w/socks/blob/master/spec/SOCKS4.protocol.txt)
- socks5 прокси - описывает [rfc 1928](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt). Есть [перевод](https://rfc2.ru/1928.rfc). Там 8 страниц и все просто описано. rcf 1929 описывает как логин-пароль передать
- в самой википедии [тоже написано](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS), но другими словами.

Comment: А для http проксей есть документация?